# Java JMH run method with multiple parameters

Tags: java, multithreading, benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I am trying to performance test a web app under load. I want to increase the number of users to check how that will affect the system's behavior. I intend to use JMH wit Java. I have already written the code to open the browser and log in. Here it is:

```
@Threads(3)
    @Benchmark
    //@BenchmarkMode(Mode.All)
    public static boolean testLogin() throws IOException {
        count = count +1;
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "firefoxdriver\\geckodriver.exe");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        //options.setHeadless(true);

        //driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        FirefoxOptions firefoxOptions = new FirefoxOptions();
        firefoxOptions.setAcceptInsecureCerts(true);
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(firefoxOptions);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        //wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,10,1);
        //initializeDriver();


        login = new Login(driver);

        Pair<String, String> user = users.get(count);
        String username = user.getKey();
        Strings password = user.getValue();


        //System.out.println(username+"  - -  "+password);

        login.login(username, password);

        driver.close();

        return true;
        //return null;
    }
```

And the setup method reading all the user credentials from a file:

```
static ArrayList<Pair> users;

static int count;
@Setup
    public void readUsers(){
        String line = "";
        String split_by = ",";
        BufferedReader bufferedReader;

        users = new ArrayList<>();
        
        try {
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("users/users.csv"));
            line = bufferedReader.readLine();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] user_entry = line.split(split_by);
                Pair<String, String> user;
                String username = user_entry[2];
                String password  = user_entry[3];

                user = new Pair<>(username, password);
                users.add(user);

                //System.out.println(username +"  - -  "+password);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        count = 0;
    }
```

Now my problem is how to run the login method using a different set of username and password as the system only allows a user one session at a time. I have no idea how to pass the values to login method. I tried using an integer index to retrieve User objects from an ArrayList, but running the code using threads calls the same value over and over. How do I tackle that problem. Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object that is unique to each test thread.

```
@State(value = Scope.Thread)
public static class ThreadState{
    String loginid;
    @Setup(Level.Trial)
    public void setup(){
           loginid = ... // load some unique login id
    }

    @TearDown(Level.Trial)
    public void teardown(){}
}

@Benchmark
public void testLogin(ThreadState state){
   String loginid = state.loginId;
   ... 
}
```

JMH will create an instance of this ThreadState for each worker thread and here you can add your 'per thread' state.